# What would cause a fat face but skinny body? Collagen?

Tags: body-fat, face, swelling, collagen

Trying to understand how this would occur - why would someone's face be fat (either in general or compared to body) when the rest of their body is toned/lean/skinny. Ive observed this personally for years and in others -

I read that excess sugar can cause excess collagen in face, thus causing the "bloating" look. What else might be the cause of a disproportionately fat face/neck when the person appears skinny everywhere else?

If they consume a high amount of one food (for example nuts)- could this be a permanent state of allergic reaction?

How would one narrow the factors to determine what is causing the "face fat"?

Comment: If it's constant and stable from birth, it's probably genetic. Enlarged facial bones in acromegaly can result in big head appearance - this happens in adults. Fat deposits in Cushing's disease give an appearance of "moon face."

Comment: if it only started during adolescence, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It depends what it is. I mentioned only 2 of many possible causes in my above comment. It's unlikely someone her will guess what it is just from a simple description. If you are concerned, visit a doctor who can give you an exact diagnosis and tell you what can be done.